# Cannot post ref id to parrent collection mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

Im trying to insert two records into mongoDB. One as a new collection the other a ref id.

**Sample of schema**
Company{
name: Acme Company,
Locations: [refID]
}

the id & location payload will be sent in the body of the request.

```js
addNewLocation: (req, res) => {
        
        let {id, ...payload} = req.body;
        
        db.Location.create(payload)
            .then( record => {
                let refId = record._id
                db.Company.findOneAndUpdate( {_id: id} , { $push: { locations: refId } }, { new: true })
            })
            .then( result => {
                res.status(201).json({success: true},{result})
            })
            .catch( err => {
                res.status(422).json({success: false},{err})
            })
    }
```

when viewing the update (on Robo3T) it appears to be inserting a document into the location, but it doesn't insert the ref id in the companies collection. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
createNewLocation: (req, res) => {
    let { companyId , ...payload } = req.body;

    db.Location.create(payload)
    .then(({_id}) => {
       return db.Company.findOneAndUpdate(companyId, {$push:{location: _id}},{new: true})
    })
    .then(()=>{
        res.status(201).json({success: true})
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        res.status(422).json({success: false})
    })
}
```

Here is the solution, just needed a return.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you mistake  locations spelling  case when you want to push ref
It may be **Locations** as you schema filed name or change your schema field to **locations**.
You can try by this in your company schema

```
 {
    name: String,
    locations:[
      {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Location"
     }
    ]
 }
```

Comment: in the models it was "Location"

Comment: use 

db.Company.findOneAndUpdate( {_id: id} , { $push: { Location: refId } }, { new: true })
            })